# How to use "findFiles" in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkinsfile contains this stage:

```
stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        script {
            def rpmFiles = findFiles glob: "**/*.rpm"
            def rpmFile = rpmFiles[0]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this to deploy an artifact to a server. How can I avoid the following error?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'findFiles' found among steps [...]
```

Answer (score 24):

`findFiles` step is a part of [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) so you have to install it if you want to use that step.

Answer (score 13):

While this answer isn't directly fixing the issue of the original question - the plugin wasn't installed - search engines do redirect to this question, and I found the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) a bit lacking. So I wanted to complement the answer a bit on how to use `findFiles`.

As I wasn't completely satisfied by the documentation I looked at the source code and the [FindFilesStep](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FindFilesStepTest.java) tests especially. There's one with this line in particular that showcase best how to use `findFiles`:

```
def files = findFiles(glob: '**/*.txt', excludes: 'b/*.txt,**/aba/*.txt')
```

As a reminder the patterns are [*ant style* patterns](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns). For example I wanted a task that included every file and folders but the hidden folder `.asccidoctor`, I wrote:

```
def docFiles
dir('build/docs/asciidoc/') {
    docFiles = findFiles(glob: '**', excludes: '**/.asciidoctor/**')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We use this with the following syntax:

```
def rpmFiles = findFiles(glob: "**/*.rpm")
```

- see also the documentation on https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/